# Android: Best approach for saving images in Room database

Tags: android, bitmap, android-room, android-bitmap

I have a room data base with 2 entities that save images as bitmaps. But I've encountered a problem where if I try to save images that are larges(1.5MB+) which are most of the pictures taken by modern smartphones, when I try to retrieve it, the app crushes because it can only have 1MB of data.

I've tried to compress the bitmap before inserting it using https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor, but it's complicated because you can't limit the size, and bitmaps are larger than what they are on files.

So I thought about 3 approaches for saving the images, an my question is which one is the best(and easy to implement), or whether there is a better approach than those.

1. compressing the bitmaps before saving - which is complicated and didn't work for very large files.
2. saving the Uri in the database instead, but if you delete the image from the phone than the image isn't saved in the database which is unexpected behavior for the user.
3. saving the image in storage than saving the Uri to the image - but it requires asking for permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: how about save the image as base64? it saves as text, then you can rebuild later

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA but isn't it still gonna be big when trying to retrieve it from the database? working with bitmaps works, but retrieving large images is my problem

Comment: it may be bigger than the actual size, but you can reduce it by compressing the bitmap then convert to base64. later you are retrieving from room as a long text then you rebuild this as a bitmap again. i'm not sure but you can give it a shot

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA actually I wrote in the post that compressing the bitmap for my use is more complicated than it seems and that's why I wrote the post in the first time...but thank you very much anyway

Comment: "saving the image in storage than saving the Uri to the image - but it requires asking for permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" -- that depends entirely on where you are saving it. So, save it to a location identified by a method on `Context`, such as `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, or `getExternalCacheDir()`. Those do not require permissions on Android 4.4+, and the first two do not require permissions on any version of Android. Then, save path details in your database.